# Insert Person/Employee into organizational unit programmatically (like PPOME)?

Tags: abap, sap-erp

Is there a way to insert a Person into an organizational unit programmatically?

Like it is done with transaction PPOME manually.

I found some related function modules, but they seem to be intended for user interfaces of transactions like PPOME and operate on internal buffers.

I'm working in ECC 6.0

Comment: I think I found something to answer my own question...Function Module RH_RELATION_MAINTAIN. As I'm trying at the moment, this is not good enough for a fun answer.

Comment: I think I found something to answer my own question...Function Module RH_RELATION_MAINTAIN. As I'm checking at the moment, this is not good enough for a full answer.  (Comment with less typos, can't change the first comment)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you do not assign persons (object type P) to org. units. Only positions (object type S) are assigned to org. units. This assignment is usually done by personnel actions (Hiring, organizational change, ...).

As this relation affects two different frameworks (PA and PD) the given task is not that simple.

Start from PA framework and insert a new infotype 0001 record for the employee with the desired org. unit. When using the decoupled infotype framework for this, please ensure PD/PA integration is turned on (View T77S0, group = PLOGI, field = PDPA). Otherwise the PD framework does not maintain the relation for you. As this affects a lot of other fields (controlling area, cost center, ...) you will probably have to use a personnel action for this task, means infotype 0000 has to be inserted as well.

Unfortunately I cannot provide examples for you ritht now. But based on your questions I would recommend to learn the delevopment basics for the HCM Module first.